# Replacing text in a .txt file (C++)

Tags: c++, html

I have multiple .html files on my desktop, all of which are linked together, but according to my own directory. Meaning that if these files were placed on a different computer, the links would not work. I am trying to make a program in C++ that will:
1) Find the username of the computer it is on. (I've gotten that far!)
2) Replace the username in the directory in the individual links in the html files with the new username. 
    I have researched thoroughly and i found one person's way of replacing certain strings. However, when I attempted to do the same trick, it cleared the entire file. Here is my program as it is:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <Windows.h>
     #include <gl/GL.h>
     #include <gl/GLU.h>
     #include <windows.h>
     #include <WinBase.h>
     #include <string>
     #include <fstream>
     #include <algorithm>
     using namespace std;

     int main()
     {
         TCHAR name [ UNLEN + 1 ];
         DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
         GetUserName( (TCHAR*)name, &size );

         string search_string = "Christian";
         string replace_string = "name";
         string inbuf;
         fstream input_file("kormain.txt", ios::in);
         ofstream output_file("kormain.txt");

         while (!input_file.eof())
         {
             getline(input_file, inbuf);

             int spot = inbuf.find(search_string);
             if(spot >= 0)
             {
                 string tmpstring = inbuf.substr(0,spot);
                 tmpstring += replace_string;
                 tmpstring += inbuf.substr(spot+search_string.length(), inbuf.length());
                 inbuf = tmpstring;
             }

             output_file << inbuf << endl;
         }
         system ("PAUSE");
         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: The proper solution would be relative URI's. That way even works on websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the same file for reading and writing and then not checking the status. This is likely to cause problems (depending on your OS).

As a quick test, change your `output_file` to write to a different file name and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: Thank you! I'm guessing it is just not compatible with unicode?

Comment: No, wouldn't have anything to do with unicode. Depending on the OS the open to write might fail because you have already opened to read. Or perhaps it works, but once you write to it, the read starts to have problems. The other "fix" would be to check the status after opening the file(s).